# Test cloud VM performance

Tags: linux, performance, monitoring, cloud

I have a linux VM hosted in a cloud environment. I suspect the provider to do too much overprovisioning with CPU and IO, from time to time.

For example postgresql's reports 300ms+ queries that are done under 5ms in explain analyse mode. 
I also observe latency with ssh while the vCPU is idle.

Which tool(s) could I use to monitor evolution of performance of CPU and IO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the box itself, you can use `vmstat` and `iostat` (part of the sysstat package).

- `vmstat 1` will show you `steal`, which is the amount of cpu cycles that the hypervisor diverted from the VM to allocate to other VMs. You can also look at `iowait`, which is the % of cpu cycles spent waiting for I/O to complete.
- `iostat -x -d 1` will show you `svctm` and `await`; respectively the average time it took for the underlying devices to service requests (after they have been processed by the I/O scheduler), and the average wait time for I/O requests. If any is higher than you expect (~10ms), this should be a sure signe of contention.